# Intel Arc A380 working in host machine. But cannot get it to passthrough to docker containers

Tags: drivers, graphics, intel-graphics

Recently purchased an Intel Arc A380 because I saw multiple people posting that they were able to use them for plex transcoding. I followed all the documentation provided on Intels website. Upgraded OS and Kernel (Currently on Ubuntu 22.04.4 LTS, Kernel 6.5.0-25) I have verified that it is showing as a VGA controller. But anytime I begin transcoding CPU usage gets stuck around 80% usage. Further indications exists when checking portainer which states that their are no GPUs connected. I have tried adding the passthrough in my docker compose however anytime the "capabilities: [gpu]" line is present it gives me an error stating that "nvidia-container-cli" is not present.

```
sudo lspci -v | grep -A8 VGA
```

Returns:

```
00:01.0 VGA compatible controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Wani [Radeon R5/R6/R7 Graphics] (rev e6) (prog-if 00 [VGA controller])
        Subsystem: Micro-Star International Co., Ltd. [MSI] Wani [Radeon R5/R6/R7 Graphics]
        Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 51, IOMMU group 0
        Memory at d0000000 (64-bit, prefetchable) [size=256M]
        Memory at f0800000 (64-bit, prefetchable) [size=8M]
        I/O ports at f000 [size=256]
        Memory at fe800000 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=256K]
        Expansion ROM at fe840000 [disabled] [size=128K]
        Capabilities: [48] Vendor Specific Information: Len=08 <?>
--
2c:00.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation Device 56a5 (rev 05) (prog-if 00 [VGA controller])
        Subsystem: ASRock Incorporation Device 6004
        Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 47, IOMMU group 2
        Memory at fd000000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=16M]
        Memory at e0000000 (64-bit, prefetchable) [size=256M]
        Expansion ROM at 000c0000 [disabled] [size=128K]
        Capabilities: [40] Vendor Specific Information: Len=0c <?>
        Capabilities: [70] Express Endpoint, MSI 00
        Capabilities: [ac] MSI: Enable+ Count=1/1 Maskable+ 64bit+
```

I can provide any extra information I just dont know what else would be relevant. I cannot for the life of me figure out how to get this GPU to show up. I also find it very odd that it keeps erroring out with the nvidia message.

Answer (score 0):

Edit: Spent hours trying to figure this out and couldnt for the life of me. As soon as I made the post I tried something new and it worked.

Adding the following two lines to my docker-compose fixed all the issues and the GPU now shows in plex as a transcoding device.

```
devices: [/dev/dri]
privileged: true
```